# Disposição dinâmica de botões em Layout Android

Tags: android-layout

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que precisa ter na tela inicial uma série de botões personalizados. A quantidade de botões que será exibida será configurada. Tendo essas informações a disposição, como posso implementar a organização deles para que se posicionem de formas diferentes na tela?

O meu objetivo é ir tentando sempre centralizar eles deixando dispostos em colunas e linhas e tendo no máximo 3 colunas de botões.

Pensei em usar RecyclerView mas não sei se conseguirei fazer a aplicação desta maneira. Com a experiência de vocês o que me recomendam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui encontrar a forma que resolve meu problema. O que fiz foi implementar o [Grid Layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) que também é uma lista mas que é exibida em linhas e colunas que posso calcular dinamicamente pra conseguir exibir e posicionar meus elementos da melhor maneira.

Deixo como referência o link do vídeo que utilizei:
[Android Studio Tutorial - Grid View](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbEHxkAEumU)

Créditos e agradecimentos ao canal 
[EDMT Dev](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCllewj2bGdqB8U9Ld15INAg) pelo vídeo prático, rápido e muito bem feito sobre o tema.

Answer (score 0):

Dependendo da forma que você quiser posicionar e, se for somente botões, você pode criar o layout com inúmeros botões, deixar a visibilidade invisible ou gone (Dependendo da situação) e ir setando a visibilidade programaticamente. 
Como cada botão vai ter seu id e você pode mudar a característica de cada um programaticamente.